# title in tab of browser empty in shiny dashboard page

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Though there is the posibility to add a title in a shiny dashboard app, which appears correctly in the app page,

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "my title"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It does not appear as the name of tab of the browser. As name of tab in browser only appears the URL (like 127...).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the browser page title like this

```
ui <- dashboardPage(title="Browser title",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  ...
```